# Is there any way to get if an AutomationElement is selected or not

Tags: c#

Check if AutomationElement is selected or not. I have used following code to get an AutomationElement object.

```
System.Windows.Point point = new System.Windows.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
AutomationElement  element = AutomationElement.FromPoint(point);
//how to know element is selected or not
```

Answer (score 1):

If your element is contained in an `ItemContainer` control (i.e. ListBox, GridView, ComboBox and so forth), then you can use the `SelectionItem` pattern on the element itself.

`SelectionItemPattern selectionItemPattern = element.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as SelectionItemPattern;
bool isSelected = selectionItemPattern.Current.IsSelected;`

Comment: The control may implement the selection pattern even if it is not inside an ItemContainer. To be safe, check the value of selectionItemPattern against null.

Comment: Or use the safe TryGetCurrentPattern method.